# Unable to open images downloaded using beautiful soup library

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a script that downloads images from webpages using the BeautifulSoup library. When I use a site such as http://www.google.com, the image downloads correctly to a folder on my desktop and I can open it up and view it. However, when I use a site such as https://sites.google.com/site/imagesizetesting/one-1, the an image appears  download to the correct folder desktop, but I get an error message saying "Paint cannot read this file. This is not a valid bitmap file, or its format is not currently supported." I think it may have to do with the fact that file path in the html file for google's home page is relative, it's /images/srpr/logo4w.png, while the path for the image contained on https://sites.google.com/site/imagesizetesting/one-1 is not relative, it's /rsrc/1370373631437/one-1/Test.png">https://sites.google.com/site/imagesizetesting//rsrc/1370373631437/one-1/Test.png. I don't know if the diffence in how the sources for the images are what causing it or if it's something else. Any ideas? Here is my code for parsing and downloading the images.

```
for image in soup.findAll("img"):
        print "Old Image Path: %(src)s" % image
        #Get file name
        filename = image["src"].split("/")[-1]
        #Get full path name if url has to be parsed
        parsedURL[2] = image["src"]
        image["src"] = '%s\%s' % (phonepath,filename)
        print 'New Path: %s' % image["src"]
        outpath = os.path.join(out, filename)

        #retrieve images
        if image["src"].lower().startswith("http"):
            urlretrieve(image["src"], outpath)
            print image["src"].lower()
        else:
            urlretrieve(urlparse.urlunparse(parsedURL), outpath) #Constructs URL from tuple (parsedURL)
            print image["src"].lower()
```

Comment: If you do Save Picture as in the browser and store it in your HD, does Paint is able to open it?

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks for the attempted help though Paulo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! Here is my updated code in case anyone else has a similar issue.

```
for image in soup.findAll("img"):
        print "Old Image Path: %(src)s" % image
        #Get file name
        filename = image["src"].split("/")[-1]
        #Get full path name if url has to be parsed
        parsedURL[2] = image["src"]
        image["src"] = '%s\%s' % (phonepath,filename)
        #Old File path (local to computer)
        #image["src"] = '%s\%s' % (out,filename)
        print 'New Path: %s' % image["src"]
        #       print image
        outpath = os.path.join(out, filename)

        #retrieve images
        if parsedURL[2].lower().startswith("http"):
            #urlretrieve(image["src"], outpath)
            urlretrieve(parsedURL[2], outpath)
            print image["src"].lower()
        else:
            print "HTTP INFO " + urlparse.urlunparse(parsedURL)
            print "HTTP INFO " + image["src"].lower()
            urlretrieve(urlparse.urlunparse(parsedURL), outpath) #Constructs URL from tuple (parsedURL)
            #print image["src"].lower()
```